# remove last div dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have structure like this

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="profile-activity clearfix">..</div>
    <div class="profile-activity clearfix">..</div>
</div>
```

This number of profile-activity clearfix is not fixed. 
How can I remove last div `profile-activity clearfix` under `col-sm-6` dynamically?

Comment: `$('.col-sm-6 .profile-activity.clearfix:last').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('col-sm-6 > .profile-activity.clearfix:last-child').remove();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [:last](https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/) selector

> Selects the last matched element.

*Code*

```
$('.col-sm-6 .profile-activity.clearfix:last').remove()
```

Comment: It should be noted that `.last` is a jQuery-specific extension and is therefore not executed natively, making it slower than using `:last-child` which is. In this case they are functionally identical. See the notes at https://api.jquery.com/last-selector/

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes Do you have a benchmark test to prove it's slower?

Comment: Added the link to the official jQuery site explicitly stating it.

Answer (score 1):

This is in CSS:

```
.col-sm-6 .profile-activity:last-child {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: This is a solution, but it only hides the element from browser users, which may not be what the poster requires. And you're missing a . in front of the .profile-activity.

Comment: Fixed. The OP didn't specify jQuery or CSS. As his tags include CSS, I decided to offer this solution.

Answer (score 0):

***How can I remove last div profile-activity clearfix under col-sm-6 dynamically?***

You can use `:last` to target last element along with `.remove()` for removing it:

```
$('.col-sm-6 .clearfix:last').remove();
```

Comment: That's uhm... kinda non-specific.

Answer (score 0):

`:last` filters the last div and `.remove()` will remove the div.

```
$(".col-sm-6 > div").remove("div:last");
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c8cg9whv/) will do the stuff.

**Code**

```
$('.col-sm-6 .profile-activity').eq($('.col-sm-6 .profile-activity').length - 1).remove();
```